# How to prove an equality involving an infinity series and the modified Bessel functions?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, bessel-functions

Using a different approach I computed the Fourier expansion of a certain function whose Fourier expansion was already computed in a certain paper. If both results are correct this would imply a certain equality which I want to present here. My question here is if there are direct ways to show the truth of the equality.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(s+n) (4 \pi \alpha \beta)^{s+n}}{\Gamma(2s+n) n! (\alpha+\beta)^{s+n-1/2}}  K_{s+n-1/2}(2 \pi (\alpha+\beta))\\
=2 \pi (\alpha\beta)^{1/2} I_{s-1/2} (2 \pi  \beta) K_{s-1/2}(2\pi  \alpha)
$$
Here $s \in \mathbb C$ with $\Re(s)>1/2$ and $\alpha \ge \beta>0$.
The functions $I_s$ and $K_s$ are just the usual modified Bessel functions of the first and second kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To evaluate the l.h.s. series
\begin{equation}
 S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(s+n) (4 \pi \alpha \beta)^{s+n}}{\Gamma(2s+n) n! (\alpha+\beta)^{s+n-1/2}}  K_{s+n-1/2}(2 \pi (\alpha+\beta))
\end{equation}
we use the [integral representation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E8) for the modified Bessel function:
\begin{equation}
 K_{\nu}\left(z\right)=\frac{\pi^{\frac{1}{2}}(\frac{1}{2}z)^{\nu}}{\Gamma\left(\nu+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-z\cosh t}(\sinh t)^{2\nu}\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
with $\nu=s+n-1/2$ and $z=2\pi(\alpha+\beta)$ to express
\begin{equation}
 S=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (4 \pi^2 \alpha \beta)^{s+n}}{\Gamma(2s+n) n!}
 \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi(\alpha+\beta)\cosh t}(\sinh t)^{2s+2n-1}\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
All the terms are positive, then changing the order of summation and integration gives
\begin{equation}
 S=\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{d}t\,e^{-2\pi(\alpha+\beta)\cosh t}(\sinh t)^{2s-1}(4 \pi^2 \alpha \beta)^{s}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ (4 \pi^2 \alpha \beta)^{n}}{ n!\Gamma(2s+n)}
 (\sinh t)^{2n}
\end{equation}
With the [series expansion](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.25.E2) of the modified Bessel function of the first kind:
\begin{equation}
 I_{\nu}\left(z\right)=(\tfrac{1}{2}z)^{\nu}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\tfrac{1}{4}z^{2})^{n}}{n!\Gamma\left(\nu+n+1\right)}
\end{equation}
we deduce, by taking $\nu=2s-1,z=4\pi\sqrt{\alpha\beta}\sinh t$,
\begin{equation}
  S=2\pi\sqrt{\alpha\beta}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-2\pi(\alpha+\beta)\cosh t}I_{2s-1}\left( 4\pi\sqrt{\alpha\beta}\sinh t \right)\mathrm{d}t
\end{equation}
This integral is tabulated (G.& R. (6.669.4)) (Aaternatively it could be evaluated as a tabulated Laplace transform (Ederlyi TI (4.17.15))
by changing $u=\cosh t-1$),
\begin{align}
 \int_0^\infty e^{-\tfrac12(a_1+a_2)\cosh x}I_{2\mu}(\sqrt{a_1a_2}\sinh x)\mathrm dx=\frac{\Gamma(1/2+\mu)}{\sqrt{a_1a_2}\Gamma(1+2\mu)}W_{0,\mu}(a_1)M_{0,\mu}(a_2)
\end{align}
where $W_{0,\mu}(a_1)$ and $M_{0,\mu}(a_2)$ are Whittaker functions. This identity is valid for $\Re(\mu+1/2)>0,\Re \mu>0,a_1>a_2$. Here, with $\alpha>\beta$ and $s>1/2$, we take $a_1=4\pi\alpha,a_2=4\pi\beta,\mu=s-1/2$. Remarking that ([DLMF1](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.18.E8)) and ([DLMF2](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.18.E9))
\begin{align}
 W_{0,\mu}\left(2z\right)&=\sqrt{\frac{2z}{\pi}}K_\mu\left(z\right)\\
 M_{0,\mu}\left(2z\right)&=2^{2\mu+\frac{1}{2}}\Gamma\left(1+\mu\right)\sqrt{z}I_{\mu}\left(z\right)
\end{align}
we obtain
\begin{equation}
 S=2\pi\sqrt{\alpha\beta}
 \frac{\Gamma(s)\Gamma\left(s+1/2\right)}{\sqrt{4\pi}\Gamma(2s)}2^{2s}I_{2s-1/2}\left(2\pi\beta\right)K_{s-1/2}\left(2\pi\alpha\right)
\end{equation}
Finally, using the Gamma [duplication formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E5),
\begin{equation}
 S=2\pi\sqrt{\alpha\beta}
 I_{s-1/2}\left(2\pi\beta\right)K_{s-1/2}\left(2\pi\alpha\right)
\end{equation}
which is the expected result.

Comment: Nice solution. $\to +1$

Comment: Merci, Claude !

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm quite happy now that this in particular confirms my computation :)

Comment: You write "all the terms are positive". I think this applies only for $s$ being real. But I guess if you show the equation for real $s$ the rest follows by analytic continuation.

Comment: That's right! It is the lazy way... I forgot the case $s$ complex.

Comment: @PaulEnta I'm quite impressed of you finding just the right integral representations and integral formulars (for example 6.669.4). How did you do that? Do you have a general advice? I'd like to have that skill as well. Could help me a lot in future ;-)

Comment: No special skills are needed! You can select an integral representation where the summation index is involved as an exponent in order to simplify the series evaluation. In this respect the DLMF page is very useful as it gives a simple access to the major representations at once. By choosing [this one](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.32.E10), for example, one gets a nice integral representation for the series:
$$S=\pi\sqrt{\alpha\beta}\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-\frac1t-\pi^2(\alpha^2+\beta^2)t\right)I_{s-1/2}\left(2\pi^2 \alpha \beta t\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}t}{t}$$