# Why is $\frac{1}{m+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-2n-m-1} (2n+m)!}{(n+m+1)!n!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital, bessel-functions

I have the strong assumption that for $m \in \mathbb N_0$ we have
$$\frac{1}{m+1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-2n-m-1} (2n+m)!}{(n+m+1)!n!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-2n-m-1}}{2n+m+1}\binom{2n+m+1}{n}.$$
But I didn't find an explicit way to show it.

In case you wanna know where this series is from: I'm still trying to solve [How to prove an equality involving an infinity series and the modified Bessel functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268118/how-to-prove-an-equality-involving-an-infinity-series-and-the-modified-bessel-fu). If you plug in $s=\alpha=\beta=1$ you eventually come up with the series equation from above. At least the series equation would show the special case (in fact the other direction is not true).

Comment: would showing that the sum is a "Taylor-ish" series for $\frac{1}{m+1}$ work?

Comment: @Nyra Is it? Developed in which point?

Comment: @ principal-ideal-domain, I don't know if it is, by that is where my head went when looking at it. i was poking the series expanded around $m=0$ (as it gives the coefficients$=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$). But looking at it now, expanding around $m=1$ would give coefficients$=\frac{(-2)^{-n}}{n!}$ (i think)

Comment: @Nyra Keep in mind that expanding at $m=1$ gives a radius of convergence of $2$. But we want to plug in arbitrary large values.

Comment: @ principal-ideal-domain, I'd forgotten about the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pssible idea could be to use

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-(2n+m+1)}\, (2n+m)!}{(n+m+1)!\,\,n!}x^{-n}=\frac{ \, _2F_1\left(\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+2}{2};m+2;\frac 1x\right)}{(m+1)\,\,2^{(m+1)}}$$ which is true even if $m$ is not an integer.

Now, working a little the expression

$$f(x)=\frac x {m+1} \left(1+\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}\right)^{-m}\left(1-\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}}\right)$$

Comment: That's a great idea but more complicated than needed. I had almost the same idea before but didn't realize that using the Legendre duplication formula you can turn $(2n+m)!$ into a product of two Gamma functions whose argument grows with $n$ (instead of $2n$). Then you simply have to evaluate the hypergeometric function at $1$. This is allowed in case $\Re(c-b-a)>0$ which is here the case (we have $c-b-a=1/2$). So then for evaluating at $1$ there is an explicit formular: $\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-b-a)/\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c-b)$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain. I made it general on purpose because if felt that it would work for any $m$. Moreover, using $x$ gives interesting formulae.

Comment: What I'm saying works for general $m$ as well. The difference is just that I directly evaluate at $1$ instead of building up a function. So I do not need to find a different representation for the hypergeometric function at the given parameters.

Comment: I just added what I mean as answer that you can see. Of course, once you rewrite the sum with using the Gamma function it holds for arbitrary $m$ as long as you don't run into poles.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I post my approch which is based on the idea of [Claude Leibovici](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82404/claude-leibovici) for clarity.

Using Legendre duplication we have
$$(2n+m)!=\Gamma(2n+m+1) = \Gamma(n+ \tfrac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(n+ \tfrac{m+2}{2})2^{2n+m}/\sqrt{\pi}.$$

So we have
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^{-2n-m-1} (2n+m)!}{(n+m+1)!n!}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{ \Gamma(n+ \tfrac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(n+ \tfrac{m+2}{2})}{\Gamma(n+m+2)n!}\\
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{ \Gamma(\tfrac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{m+2}{2})}{\Gamma(m+2)} F(\tfrac{m+1}{2},\tfrac{m+2}{2},m+2,1)\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{ \Gamma(\tfrac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{m+2}{2})}{\Gamma(m+2)} \frac{\Gamma(m+2)\Gamma(m+2-\tfrac{m+1}{2}-\tfrac{m+2}{2})}{\Gamma(m+2-\tfrac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(m+2-\tfrac{m+2}{2})}\\
= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{ \Gamma(\tfrac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{m+2}{2})}{\Gamma(m+2)} F(\tfrac{m+1}{2},\tfrac{m+2}{2},m+2,1)\\
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} \frac{ \Gamma(\tfrac{m+1}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{m+2}{2})}{\Gamma(m+2)} \frac{\Gamma(m+2)\Gamma(\tfrac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\tfrac{m}{2}+\tfrac{3}{2})\Gamma(\tfrac{m}{2}+\tfrac{2}{2})}
=\frac{1}{m-1}.
$$